# Why am I able to call on String class methods with a String literal?

Tags: java, string

First of all, I am using the Drjava interactions pane to test all the codes that I am posting here(I do not have access to any other IDE in my current situation).
I have noticed that I am able to call methods that belong to the String class with string literals as well as string objects. That is,

```
String s1 = "a";
```

s1 has access to all String methods such as getBytes(), length(), charAt(), etc.

While in the case of integers, an int variable doesn't have access to the methods that are within the Integer class.

Why is this the case?

On a side note:

When I try to compare two string literals with the same value, as in

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "b";

s1 == s2;
```

The boolean I get is false, which is not supposed to be the case according to the numerous post/articles I have read on string literals vs string objects.

Does this have something to do with how the Drjava functions specifically? Is that a part of why I am able to call on String methods with string literals?

Comment: `Integer` variable would have that access. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: A literal doesn't matter. You're looking at the differences between objects and primitives

Answer (score 3):

A `String` literal is a reference to an instance of the `String` class (Java 8 Language Specification - 3.10.5 String Literals), so it's perfectly normal to be able to call methods on it. There's no difference between references to `String` instances (like variables) and `String` literals, they're one and the same.

On the other hand, an `int` is a primitive type, different from an `Integer`, which is a class that can have its own instances.

Finally, you should never use `==` to compare objects *unless* you want to compare them for identity, normally you should use `equals()` for testing equality. And why are you surprised that `"a" == "b"` returns `false`? they're not equal, much less, identical.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are objects. integers are primitives.

In order to compare two strings, you have to use string1.equals(string2).